# How to get the second last message from a channel discord py

Tags: python, discord, message

i'm trying to make a command that edit the second last message (after the !command message) embed in a channel, but i cant find a way to get the second last message; i get this error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

I tried this block of code :

```
@bot.command()
async def edit(ctx,gif):

  channel=ctx.channel
  messages = await channel.history(limit=2).flatten()
  second_to_last_message_id = messages[1].id

  await ctx.message.delete()

  msg = await channel.fetch_message(second_to_last_message_id)
  
  print(msg)

  a=msg.embeds[0]
  
  a.set_image(url=gif)
  
  await msg.edit(embed=msg.embeds[0])
```

If anyone could help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use list comprehension to get a list of messages from the async generator since the `flatten()` function has been removed:

```
messages = [message async for message in channel.history(limit=2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I was spending so much time on this!!